# regex to get everything between apostrophes but do not return apostrophes

Tags: php, regex

i am using the following code to grab the challenge

```
preg_match("/'03AHJ(.*?)'/", $recaptcha_page_response,$captchastring);
```

on the following text

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    challenge : '03AHJ_VuvTTaeouhgwbBXLQxnyRpYagVrS5lfF2N90aSRWHio3pAyqd6lfnHnWb_cveXafWHcgtK5zmhpetpy2NAWxfoDlCXuub3v2GUaA7EZDn0VqA6CheWWiF8yFBM3i7zN0XtKzHKItsxfcArzgmH4ARft-OWzSrOGpAM_oG0hp12cZMgWmV15FwCNCtFuypkxnPhDv8Fagw4YDInvxal8nhxIJEen6M4iBJx4KGCjolyqImbzJ54I7jFZaS9OMlK-Giv3cOq7aHUTGJeG9f9joya4WkXXKsg',
    timeout : 1800,
    lang : 'en',
    server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    site : '6LeC3O0SAAAAAC_YcSZKQChES7yidMTP_h-6uTTX',
    error_message : '',
    programming_error : '',
```

however it also returns the ' in array[0] so that this becomes

```
$captchastring = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=$captchastring[0]";
```

this

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c='03AHJ_VutYynsKzGrLzB3czHAOTgfl2jGc-r0S5fVXz9oELZQN-CbgtFqbZO0m-ZyfrcxDxw9NOWVvCZ2hsZqBY-fBNgCzW4Q1zgmLOMxgugVLYLc49GODWISsde0uKz904r-5qDC9VybX6AsmrUfAOnrgCfyKZUmGWkVtG1Zgjy5N-dQjldW_XOeWr94FlxKic-yG_9ca34fJnLZ06ol2FsYq9DeTZqsAYQ'
```

which is obviously wrong, what regex will get everything between the `''` but does not include them in the returned array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/(?<=')03AHJ[^']*/", $recaptcha_page_response,$captchastring);
```